# After installing monotouch, no begin trial choice in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

as in the title of question after installing monotouch.

I opened visual studio 2012 → new project → IOS → ipad → HelloWorld app → then after registering at xamarin and connecting from VS to xamarin no choice appeared but purchase license, so where is begin trial choice?

Comment: thanks @svick for making my question more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may have hit a bug in the latest stable release. If you contact Xamarin support they will be able to help you.

Comment: If the issue still remains, I believe this issue was fixed in the below version of Xamarin.iOS for VS. Please download it and follow the instructions to begin a trial:
http://download.xamarin.com/MonoTouchforVisualStudio/Windows/mtvs-1.1.200.0.msi